# How a delphi program can control a php CLI script?

Tags: php, delphi

I have a php script that I need to be controlled by DELPHI 
(I need a windows GUI that's why I want delphi).

I can run php script with winexec or exec

1) how can I make the php script not being opened in a command line window ?

2) How Can I communicate with delphi ?
ex: php script tells delphi that something has been captured

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ActiveScript](http://php.net/manual/fa/install.windows.activescript.php) with [Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k.aspx).